# run a cron for magento specific mode

Tags: configuration, cron

i've a module, here is a config.xml installed on a magento 1.8, 
    
    
        
            
                0.1.0

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <stockreport>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <stockreport before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ucommerz_Stockreport_Adminhtml</stockreport>
                    </modules>
                    <module>Ucommerz_Stockreport</module>
                    <frontName>stockreport</frontName>
                </args>
            </stockreport>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <models>
            <ucommerz_stockreport>
                <class>Ucommerz_Stockreport_Model</class>
            </ucommerz_stockreport>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <ucommerz_stockreport>
                <class>Ucommerz_Stockreport_Helper</class>
            </ucommerz_stockreport>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <stockreport>
                <class>Ucommerz_Stockreport_Block</class>
            </stockreport>
        </blocks>

        <template>
            <email>
                <ucommerz_stockreport_ucommerz_stockreport_settings_report_template translate="label" module="ucommerz_stockreport">
                    <label>Low Stock Notification</label>
                    <file>stockreport/emailreport.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
               </ucommerz_stockreport_ucommerz_stockreport_settings_report_template>
            </email>
        </template>

    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <ucommerz_stockreport_email>
                <run><model>ucommerz_stockreport/cron::emailreport</model></run>
                <schedule>
                    <config_path>ucommerz_stockreport/ucommerz_stockreport_settings/report_schedule</config_path>
                </schedule>
            </ucommerz_stockreport_email>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

    <default>
        <ucommerz_stockreport>
            <ucommerz_stockreport_settings>
                <report_enabled>0</report_enabled>
                <report_from_email>general</report_from_email>
                <report_to_email></report_to_email>
                <report_template>ucommerz_stockreport_ucommerz_stockreport_settings_report_template</report_template>
                <report_threshold>5</report_threshold>
                <report_exclude_disabled>1</report_exclude_disabled>
                <report_exclude_parent>1</report_exclude_parent>
                <report_schedule>0 1 * * *</report_schedule>
            </ucommerz_stockreport_settings>
        </ucommerz_stockreport>
    </default>

</config>
```

i tried set up a cron job on my linux server with this line:

```
0 1 * * * /bin/sh /var/www/directoy/cron.sh #Magento eshop
```

but it did not run, everyone know what is the problem?

--update--

when I into Linux `/bin/sh` then type the file path

```
$ /var/www/directoy/cron.php
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 1: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: cannot open ?php: No such f                                                                                   ile
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 2: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: /bin: Permission denied
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 3: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: LICENSE.html: not found
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 4: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: LICENSE.html: not found
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 5: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: LICENSE.html: not found
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 6: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: LICENSE.html: not found
/var/www/directoy/cron.php: 7: /var/www/directoy/cron.php: Syntax error: "(" unexpecte
```

Comment: does it run when you invoke it from the shell directly?

Comment: i tried, it not invoked

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: You need to test with `/bin/sh /var/www/directoy/cron.sh` not just with `/var/www/directoy/cron.php` which normally can not be executed via shell. `?php` is the beginning of (`<?php`) the php file redirected bash style. Won't work that way, you need to invoke the .sh script, not the .php script.

Comment: /bin/sh /var/www/directoy/cron.sh already tested, not invoke

Comment: if the sh script does not invoke on the shell already, then you need to debug such fundamental functionality first. Seems less a magento but more a system configuration problem. Try creating you own .sh script with just some litte echo hello world and try to get it to work. Also double check the way you check that invocation works is actually fail safe (for the check). Also ensure that you know the correct path of the PHP binary on that system taking the right PHP version and php.ini configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Install [AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) for Magento. For me it fixed a lot of issues with the cron jobs in magento. Try it on a test installation first. It gives you a list of all jobs, you can start them from the admin - a very useful module! I couldn't get the cronjobs run properly before installing this.

Comment: I never had any problems with crons after doing all with I mentionned above. But being able to have a graphical view of the crons and there timeline looks really interesting, thanks for the tip. +1

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you run Magento's cron.php (located in Magento root folder) every 5 minutes or so (in your server's crontab). Doing so, Magento will check all the XML files for your modules and check for the  nodes. Then it will add jobs to the queue in table `cron_schedule` (in your DB). After a short moment, you shoudl see this table populating. Magento will launch the crons by itself.

Hope this helped.